# Problem with AppKit namespace not being recognized in .Net MAUI project

Tags: xcode, maui, visual-studio-mac, maui-community-toolkit

I have created a .Net MAUI project after downloading macOS 14.0 and Visual Studio 2022 For Mac, as well as the latest version of XCode (15.0.1). No changes were made to the project template, and the project is able to run in Visual Studio For Mac as a Mac desktop application. But for some reason it does not recognize the 'using AppKit;' statement when I try to add that to the top of the MainPage.xaml.cs file. It even picks it up in intellisense but still gives me the "the type or namespace 'AppKit' could not be found, are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" error. The project is targeting .Net 7.0 and net7.0-maccatalyst is listed under the Dependencies in the Solution Explorer. The SDK Manager lists Apple and my XCode installation as the location.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2022 For Mac as well as XCode, and tried creating new projects from the .Net MAUI template and repeatedly restarting and cleaning/rebuilding. No luck.

Comment: MAUI is a cross platform framework.  AppKit is a Mac/iOS only API.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code

Comment: Hi Jason, appreciate the response! The issue I ran into with trying that is that AppKit still doesn't seem to be recognized even when I try to use it within a file in the Platforms/MacCatalyst folder. When I attempt it within that context, the "using AppKit;" statement is recognized, but the expected subclasses don't seem to be. For instance, if I try the statement "var test = NSScreen.MainScreen;", I get the error "the name 'NSScreen' does not exist in the current context".